# Run application with other user

Tags: linux, security, gnome, fedora

OS: Fedora 14
GUI: GNOME

I need to run an application with another user then the "default" (normally used).
Purpose: create a ".desktop" file on my desktop to run e.g.: Google Chrome with another user (NOT ROOT! - so beesu doesn't count.)
There aren't any gksu, or kdesu packages in Fedora 14. Why?

So i want to create a user with "adduser SOMEONE", and i want to run e.g.: Google Chrome with "SOMEONE" - then it will have minimum permissions, "more security".

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Fedora uses [consolehelper](http://codeidol.com/unix/fedora/Securing-Your-System/Configuring-PAM-and-consolehelper/#Id19475e23665_PAM_and_consolehelper865203) to facilitate running a program as a different user.

You should consider using SELinux to restrict the permissions and capabilities of the application instead though.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution myself:

```
xhost local:transmission-user
sudo -u transmission-user -- /usr/bin/transmission-gtk
```

Comment: THIS IS THE SOLUTION!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Currently I use this workaround, using ssh with -X parameter to pass the X session and then invoke the program I need. It's a little stupid I think (but at least it works).

Note that MB is the other user I use (I guess SSH server must be started – I think I started it an year ago).

```
nki@nki-PC-S2PV ~ $ ssh mb@localhost -X
mb@localhost's password:
Welcome to Linux Mint 12 Lisa (GNU/Linux 3.0.0-12-generic x86_64...

mb@nki-PC-S2PV ~ $ firefox
```

Comment: Lolwut. Love the idea of having a linux server with X, whose only job is running my firefox :/ >_____>

Comment: So the idea that this is just an example is so unrealistic that you don't even consider it as an option ? Interesting ;) Actually using it for Virtualbox with duplicated virtual machines where the hard disk signatures match and you can't have the same machine (hdd) twice). Regards :)

Comment: No, I wasn't saying it was unrealistic. Just that the thought had not crossed my mind. I am now colored intrigued. No malcontent meant. <3

Answer (score 0):

I wrote `ego` (Alter Ego) for exactly this use case, it automatically handles `xhost` and Wayland and PulseAudio socket sharing: https://github.com/intgr/ego

So you just run `ego chromium` or `ego -u somebody chromium`

If you run into problems, please open an issue on GitHub. I may be the only user of it, so it hasn't gotten much testing yet.

(And I notice that I'm a decade late with this answer, but hopefully it will help somebody :D)